# .py to exe without other files

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

Using pyinstaller, I created a .exe file and other files. Can I create ONLY the .exe, without other files, or is there any way to put together all files? I need your help.

[image: here is my screenshot]

Comment: Pyinstaller requires the internal dll and other files to create.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this command;
`pyinstaller --onefile your_script_name.py`

Answer (score 0):

If you are a learner, you will get good insight into how to create an exe file using PyInstaller. I provide below the github link for a very small project. You will be able to create exe using the following command.

```
setup.py clean develop install
```

Github Link : https://github.com/debjava/py-exe-creator1

First you download the project and run the above command just to see the exe.

As per the above project, you can similarly put all your project file and you can use the same command to run to create exe file using pyinstaller.